# Cannot send JSONs from an external app but my Django test works

Tags: python, json, django

Tl;dr: Im trying to send a JSON over http with python, is my first script alright?

Im trying to build a django app where I would send information to add to the database by POSTing json strings from another python application.

To do that, I run this code to send the json (trimmed to the important part)

```
out_data = {
    'session_id': session_id,
    'count': count,
    'gas_reading': gas_received,
    'latitude': latitude,
    'longitude': longitude,
    'date_time': date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")
}

out_json = json.dumps(out_data)
url = 'http://localhost:8000/sessions/post/'
response = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-type':'application/json'}, json=out_json)
print("Posted to ",url," and got ",response)
```

And this is the definition of the view that catches it.

```
def post(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        received_data=json.loads(request.body)
        session_id = int(received_data['session_id'])

        if Session.objects.filter(session_id=session_id):
            session = Session.objects.get(session_id=session_id)
        else:
            session = Session(session_id=session_id)
            session.save()

        session.measurement_set.create(
            gas_reading=int(received_data['gas_reading']),
            count=int(received_data['count']),
            latitude=float(received_data['latitude']),
            longitude=float(received_data['longitude']),
            date_time = parse_datetime(received_data['date_time'])
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    elif request.method=='GET':
        return HttpResponse("This is only for posting data")
```

I tried the View by using this test, which works:

```
class PostViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_post_into_database(self):
        data = {
            'session_id': 69,
            'count':100,
            'gas_reading': 420,
            'latitude': 4.13,
            'longitude': 80.08,
            'date_time': '2020-07-13 20:30:00'
        }
        headers = {'content-type':'application/json'}
        self.client.post(reverse('readings:post'), content_type='application/json',data=data)


        session=Session.objects.get(session_id=69)
        measurement=session.measurement_set.last()
        local_date_time = timezone.localtime(measurement.date_time)
        self.assertEqual(session.session_id, 69)
        self.assertEqual(measurement.count, 100)
        self.assertEqual(measurement.gas_reading,420)
        self.assertEqual(measurement.latitude,4.13)
        self.assertEqual(measurement.longitude,80.08)
        self.assertEqual(local_date_time.day,13)
        self.assertEqual(local_date_time.month,7)
        self.assertEqual(local_date_time.year,2020)
        self.assertEqual(local_date_time.hour,20)
        self.assertEqual(local_date_time.minute,30)
        self.assertEqual(local_date_time.second,00)
```

I get a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` and fooling around with the debugger, I see that, indeed, I get a string with the json data instead of a dictionary object. Am I missing something in sending the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is wrong:** You're converting your `out_data` to JSON and still using `json` argument to pass `out_json`.
**What you should be doing** is directly using `json` argument with dictionary or using `data` argument with converted json.

```
response = requests.post(
    url, headers={"Content-type": "application/json"}, json=out_data
)
```

OR

```
response = requests.post(
    url, headers={"Content-type": "application/json"}, data=out_json
)
```

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thank you!